# Dark matter thermally averaged cross section

Tags: cosmology, kinematics, integration, scattering-cross-section

I'm trying to rederive the results of this classic paper:
https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(91)90438-4
to find the thermally averaged cross-section. I am struggling with a change of variables and applying the right boundary conditions. For example, I want to change the phase space in Eq  (3.2) - (3.5):

$\int d^3p_1 d^3p_2 =\int 8\pi^2 dE_1dE_2 p_1 p_2 d\cos\theta$

to

$\int dE_- dE_+ ds$

where

$s=2m^2+2E_1E_2-2p_1p_2\cos\theta \quad E_{-} = E_1-E_2 \quad E_{+} = E_1+E_2$

I know how to change the integration variables but I am confused about the integration bounds. For example, I would think the integration bounds are

$\int_{m}^{\infty} dE_1\int_{m}^{\infty} dE_2  \int_{-1}^{1}d\cos\theta$

but it seems like the lower boundary for $E_+$ and $E_-$ are

$|E_-| \leq \sqrt{1-\frac{4m^2}{s}}\sqrt{E_+^2-s} \quad E_+\geq \sqrt{s}$

any input/advice gratefully received